# How to use AWS IoT MQTT with AWS Cognito User Pool

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I might sound very dumb but from a few days, I'm struggling to find out a solution on how to connect to **AWS IoT MQTT** having auth flow based on `CognitoIdentityProviderClient`.

My setup look like this:

1. **I have user pool "some-user-pool"**.
2. **I have an user in user pool "some-user-in-user-pool"**.
3. **My user pool is attached to IoT Policy "some-iot-policy"**.

What next? I mean to say that I'm already aware of the fact that I can connect to mqtt by certificate attached to policy but I want to use this via an user.

So I'm on a step where I have final `RespondToAuthChallengeResponse` after auth flow; everything went well but I cannot figure out what to do now? What can I do to setup `AwsIotMqtt5ClientBuilder` to use user pool.

I've a code something like this

```
RespondToAuthChallengeResponse response =  cognitoIdentityProviderClient.respondToAuthChallenge(request)

//After this, I have accessToken and idToken

AwsIotMqtt5ClientBuilder builder = AwsIotMqtt5ClientBuilder.newMqttBuilder(hostname)

//here I'm lost on how I can setup mqtt to use the response
```

Answer (score -1):

If you already have made the basic config, including AWS SDK and importing necessary libraries for it to work.

You need to initialize your AWS IoT and Cognito clients:

```
String userPoolId = "your-user-pool-id";
String clientId = "your-client-id";
String username = "user-username"; // username you want to authenticate

CognitoCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = CognitoCredentialsProvider.builder()
        .clientId(clientId)
        .cognitoIdentityProviderClient(yourCognitoClient)
        .build();

Region region = Region.YOUR_REGION; // Replace with your AWS region

IotClient iotClient = IotClient.builder().region(region).build();
IotDataPlaneClient dataPlaneClient = IotDataPlaneClient.builder().region(region).build();
```

Create new MQTT client:

```
AwsIotMqttConnectionBuilder builder = AwsIotMqttConnectionBuilder.newMqttConnectionBuilder("your-iot-endpoint")
        .clientId("your-client-id")
        .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .region(region)
        .protocol(AwsIotMqttConnectionBuilder.Protocol.WSS);
```

Make sure the Cognito user is associated with an IoT policy. Here is an example of how you can implement the policy to Cognito user:

```
String policyName = "your-iot-policy-name";

AttachPolicyRequest attachPolicyRequest =
AttachPolicyRequest.builder()
        .policyName(policyName)
        .target(yourCognitoIdentityId) // Replace with your Cognito Identity ID
        .build();
 
iotClient.attachPolicy(attachPolicyRequest);
```

Connect to AWS IoT MQTT:

```
AwsIotMqttConnection connection = builder.build();
connection.connect();
```

This is just a basic connection implementation of AWS IoT using Cognito, but it might help you figured out how to do it. :)

Comment: yeah, sadly this is a cpy paste from chatgpt :/ I got the same answer there but it is wrong and just adjusted wrongly. And of course, you missed it the auth part :/